# Does TFS 2015 limit the ITestCaseResult comment field to 1000 characters when set programatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015

I have a tool to update TFS Test case results based on a Jenkins test run. It will parse the results file and generate\update test cases based on the results.

When it comes to a failure it copies the standard output section of the result into the comment section in the test case result. i.e:

```
case "Failed": testCaseResult.Outcome = TestOutcome.Failed;
      testCaseResult.ErrorMessage = result.ErrorMessage;
      testCaseResult.FailureType = FailureType.Regression;
      testCaseResult.Comment = result.StdOut;
      break;
```

When I debug through it, it shows the full text string in result.StdOut and immediately after assigning the value testCaseResult.Comment will show it has the full text string too.

But after saving the result collection the test case result comments text only shows the first 1000 characters for all test cases.

```
mtm.ResultCollection.Save(false);
```

This worked fine up until we moved to TFS 2015. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening or how to get around it?

Comment: I'd recommend adding the log as an attachment. The comment is quite limited in size, as it's shown in the UI in a number of places. That's how output logs are saved in MTM as well.

Comment: Makes sense and should get me around this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to `ITestResult.Comment` property. It's using the **string** type. You could check the details of the property [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestresult.comment(v=vs.120).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

It should be the limitation of **Web UI** display. Have created a test in web and confirmed this guess.
[image]

You could be able to type the characters>1000 and it could be displayed correctly in the textbox. However when you save the comment of the test result. It will only shows the first 1000 characters in the webpage.

As a workaround you could add the log as an attachment just like *jessehouwing* recommend.